# set variable options with dot

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to interface with a system not managed by me that is doing some Unix command scripts and command to easily execute a job.

There is a variable substitution that doesn't work and I wonder if I can write a command to avoid the situation.
There are many variables to set and I want the chance to enter an empty variable.
The problem is that the system is not passing an empty variable and simply doesn't set the variable. I get

> ${option.VARIABLE}: bad substitution

I try to set something like that but isn't working.

> if [ -z ${option.VARIABLE} ]; then option.VARIABLE=""; fi;

Any idea?

Comment: Is `${option.VARIABLE}` part of the original script, or part of your attempt to work around the empty variable condition? Are you perhaps thinking of `${option:VARIABLE}` or `${option:-VARIABLE}`?

Comment: Is it possible that your _script_ is meant to be interpreted by ksh93 and makes use of disciplines?

Comment: This would be _much_ easier to answer if you could give us a minimal working example of the script that reproduces this error.

Comment: @steeldriver It's valid ksh93 syntax (see glenn's answer), and this looks like a plausible use case for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dot is not a valid character in a variable name. The bash manual says ([here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions))

> name
>
> > A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

---

However, my ksh93 man page says:

> Definitions.
>
> > [...] An identifier is a sequence of letters, digits, or underscores  start‐
> >            ing  with a letter or underscore.  Identifiers are used as components of variable names.  A vname is
> >            a sequence of one or more identifiers separated by a . and optionally preceded by a ..   Vnames  are
> >            used  as  function  and  variable  names.

This part seems most relevant to your issue (emphasis mine):

> Parameter Expansion.
>
> > [...]   A
> >            variable  is  denoted  by  a vname.  **To create a variable whose vname contains a ., a variable whose
> >            vname consists of everything before the last . must already exist.**

This feature exists only in ksh93, not in bash. If your script makes use of it, you need to run it under ksh93.

Comment: Actually, given the error message, the OP is running a ksh93 script in bash (or possibly mksh, but presumably bash given the tag).

Answer (score 2):

I think the "." in your variable name messes up your code.

Try removing that dot in your variable by e.g. renaming it from `option.VARIABLE` to `optionVARIABLE`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify that part, as the system is not under my control, and the "option." is inserted in any variable. If the variable is defined everything is working fine. This definitely a unix env, and I believe there must be a way to write a fix command for this

Comment: is it inserted in front of every variable? you can't use ${VAR} then as far as I know. try without `{}` the curly brackets. Also you can empty your variable with VAR=;, so without double quotes `"`.

Comment: Use the curly brackets is effectively working unless the variable is not filled with something, the problem  is just how to set up this variable when is not set by the system